# restrict users input to pre defined list of values

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input` tag with id `myInput` which let's users type values. I also have a autocomplete feature which is supported by an array called `countries` with pre populated values.

I want the user's to only be able to submit values that match the pre populated list.

For example i have an array with the following values -> `['USA','CHINA','RUSSIA'];`

Therefore I don't want the user to type some random input like "abc" or "xyz" I only want them to be able to submit the input that matches my list. Is this possible?

MY HTML CODE

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="getInput()">
 </div>
```

MY JS CODE

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
    the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;
    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { return false;}
        currentFocus = -1;
        /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        /*for each item in the array...*/
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
          if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
            /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            /*make the matching letters bold:*/
            b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
            /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
            /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                closeAllLists();
            });
            a.appendChild(b);
          }
        }
    });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
          increase the currentFocus variable:*/
          currentFocus++;
          /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
          addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
          /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
          decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
          currentFocus--;
          /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
          addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
          e.preventDefault();
          if (currentFocus > -1) {
            /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
            if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
          }
        }
    });
    function addActive(x) {
      /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
      if (!x) return false;
      /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
      removeActive(x);
      if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
      /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
      x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
      /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
      }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
      /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
      except the one passed as an argument:*/
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
          x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
  }

        var countries = ['USA','CHINA','RUSSIA'];
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);





function getInput(){
  alert(document.getElementById('myInput').value);
}
```

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c13zmaqg/)

The autocomplete code was taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `<datalist>` tag of HTML, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

The updated HTML code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" list="Country">
        <datalist id="Country">
            <option value="USA">
            <option value="CHINA">
            <option value="RUSSIA">
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="getInput()">
</div>
```

The content of the `<datalist>` can be dynamically changed using javascript:

```
// dynamically fill the available text input options
var countries = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'];
var objTable = document.getElementById("Country");
objTable.innerHTML += "<option>" + countries[0] + "</option>";
objTable.innerHTML += "<option>" + countries[1] + "</option>";
objTable.innerHTML += "<option>" + countries[2] + "</option>";
```

Regarding the user input restriction: you can validate the user input with javascript, and then choose to continue or abandon depending on the input validity.

If you want to restrict the user input using pure HTML, consider using the `<select>` tag, which limits the user's input to a certain scope, while still offers user friendly 'semi-auto-completion' when the keys are hit: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp